# Outlook 2007 to Outlook 2019 migration with CSV import caused mass duplication that won't stop

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I was trying to migrate my friend's Outlook from his old laptop to his new laptop and used the export/import menu item which offered CSV by default. I realized I screwed up by accepting this default. It went totally wrong and now I need help how to fix and understand the ongoing issue.

All emails since 2017 now re-download once or twice everyday and become duplicated. They also re-download on the iphone and cause massive unread emails where a legitimate email could end up lost.

This is what happened:

- old laptop has Office 2007 with account configured POP/SMTP
- new laptop has Office 2019 Pro, latest update (or at least it finds no update to it). It added the account with a Wizard, I'm not sure if it added as IMAP or SMTP.
- I export to CSV the global Inbox from the Outlook 2007.
- I create the same account on the new laptop in Outlook 2019 which is a pop3 account to someemail@sympatico.ca
- the inbox list appears empty.
- I import the CSV into Outlook of the Office 2019
- Everything seems great and I do some other things.
- After 30 minutes, gigabytes of emails are duplicated and all the devices start downloading these duplicated emails
- All the duplicates have a "Sent: None" date.
- I put the iPhone in airplane mode so it stop downloading.
- the old laptop with Outlook 2007 finishes downloading all the duplicates.
- after I put back the iphone on the wifi, it restarted to download again the next day.
- I delete the account on the new computer.
- The next day Outlook 2007 re-downloads a third time all emails. But still only two copies of each email appear but the email date of some duplicates just gets updated to the current time.

Questions:

- What caused the duplication technically speaking?
- How can I stop this duplication and massive re-download? It is still ongoing.
- What piece of software sent back the emails to the sympatico.ca email server? I thought only IMAP servers could do that.
- How can I remove the duplicates from the old computer and iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, we shouldn't export&import the messages in .csv file, it would cause the message couldn't display normally in your mailbox(sent: none).

For the issue about duplicate messages, agree with you, it wouldn't be synced if you import the messages to a pop account.

But according to your description, I noticed that you have configured the account in new computer with an unknown type at the first time. Was the POP account you configured for the second time on new computer in the same Outlook profile with the first account created by the wizard? If so, the issue may occur if you import the .csv file to the first account accidently and this is an IMAP account, we could check the account type via File>Account settings>Account settings.

Also, in normal circumstances, even if we import the data in new computer, it wouldn't affect the original pop account. For your case, I think there may be any unexpected errors in your mailbox itself.

In order to clean up the duplicate messages in your mailbox, if you could log in to the web mail, it's suggested to delete the duplicate messages there. If you don't have the web mail, you could configure the account with IMAP in new computer and delete the duplicate, and then reconfigure the account in other devices to re-sync the messages.

For deleting duplicate emails, we can delete emails in bulk through Outlook’s "Clean up Folder" option or VBA script. Here is a relevant thread: [Duplicate emails in outlook](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/510102/duplicate-emails-in-outlook.html?childToView=543933#comment-543933).

Comment: Yes indeed the add account wizard in Outlook 2019 added the account as IMAP by default without offering me the choice. That's what happened, jeez !!

Comment: Yes, if you work with auto-configure account in Outlook(add account in wizard and connect directly), Outlook would choose account type automatically--it's usually Exchange or IMAP(Gmail account is the same). For your issue, it's recommended to clean up the duplicate email first in web mail or IMAP account and re-sync to other clients.